# Convert JSON to appropriate Format using Ember Serializer

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, jsonserializer

I would like to convert the JSON object

```
{
 User:{
  'Name':"asdas",
  'Address_Line_1':"dasdasd"
  }
}
```

to form data

**Name=asdas&Address_Line_1=dasdasd**

**before sending request to my API Server**

P.S : I removed root element 'User' using **serializeIntoHash** method

Answer (score 1):

Try Using

```
$.param({'Name':"asdas", 'Address_Line_1':"dasdasd"});
```

Ember DS.Store methods will convert the params to form data format automatically. However you can do it manually using `$.params(obj)`.

`$.params(obj)` will return object props and values in form data format

Comment: Could you add some details of why this should work? Code-only answers are not very useful and are subject to deletion.

Comment: Ember DS.Store methods will convert the params to form data format automatically. However you can do it manually using $.params(obj).

$.params(obj) will return object props and values in form data format

Comment: Thanks, can you update the answer with these details?